# Textview cannot set text but Imageview working

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some problem with my code. I cannot set Textview but ImageView is working. This is my xml textview. I using adapter and listener interface.
error : textview on a null object reference

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 
    <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle" />
 
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
       android:visibility="visible"
       app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
       app:cardElevation="4dp">
 
        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
 
            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
               android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imgGambar"
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
                   android:foreground="@color/overlay_light_20"
                   app:civ_shadow="true"
                   app:civ_shadow_radius="0"
                   android:src="@drawable/photo_female_2"
                   app:civ_border="false" />
 
                <View
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_large"
                   android:layout_height="0dp" />
 
                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="vertical">
 
                    <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvName"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:gravity="center_vertical"
                       android:text="Emma Richmond"
                       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                       android:textColor="@color/grey_90" />
 
                    <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
                       android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                        <TextView
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:gravity="center_vertical"
                           android:text="in "
                           android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                           android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />
 
                        <TextView
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:gravity="center_vertical"
                           android:text="Hwy, Carthage"
                           android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                           android:textColor="@color/light_blue_400"
                           android:textStyle="bold" />
 
                    </LinearLayout>
 
                </LinearLayout>
 
            </LinearLayout>
 
            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tvKonten"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
               android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
               android:text="@string/middle_lorem_ipsum"
               android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
               android:textColor="@color/grey_60" />
 
            <View
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="1dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
               android:background="@color/grey_5" />
 
            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
               android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_large">
 
                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_vertical"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                    <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/imgLike"
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                       android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                       android:tint="@color/light_green_300"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up" />
 
                    <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/txtsuka"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:gravity="center_vertical"
                       android:text="12 likes"
                       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                       android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />
 
                </LinearLayout>
 
                <View
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_large"
                   android:layout_height="0dp" />
 
                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:gravity="center_vertical"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                    <ImageView
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                       android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                       android:tint="@color/light_blue_400"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_textsms" />
 
                    <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvKomentar"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:gravity="center_vertical"
                       android:text="4 Comments"
                       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                       android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />
 
                </LinearLayout>
 
                <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tvLalu"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="end|right"
                   android:text="2h ago"
                   android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                   android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />
 
            </LinearLayout>
 
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my adapter :  https://pastebin.com/csiW52h4

```
public class AdapterCardPostList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCardPostList.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<PostItem> list;
    private List<Check> checkList;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;


    public AdapterCardPostList(Context context, List<PostItem> list, List<Check> checkList, OnItemClickListener monItemClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.checkList = checkList;
        this.mOnItemClickListener = monItemClickListener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public ImageView image, imglike;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView konten;
        public TextView like;
        public TextView komentar;
        public TextView lalu;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image    = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgGambar);
            name     = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            konten   = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvKonten);
            like     = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtsuka);
            komentar = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvKomentar);
            lalu     = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLalu);
            imglike  = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
            imglike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, checkList.get(getAdapterPosition()), getAdapterPosition(), list.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });

        }
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }



     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
             PostItem p = list.get(position);
             holder.konten.setText(p.getContent());
             holder.like.setText(p.getLike());
             holder.name.setText(p.getName());
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
             //sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
             try {
                // long time = sdf.parse(p.getTanggal()).getTime();
                 Date date = sdf.parse(p.getTanggal());
                 long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 CharSequence ago =
                         DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.getTime(), now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
                 holder.lalu.setText(ago);
             } catch (ParseException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         holder.komentar.setText(p.getKomen() + " Comments");
             Glide.with(context).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + p.getUid() + "/picture?type=normal").into(holder.image);
             if (p.getUid().equals(MainActivity.id)){
                 holder.imglike.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red_200), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                 checkList.add(new Check(true));
             }else{
                 holder.imglike.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.light_green_300), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                 checkList.add(new Check(false));
             }

     }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

my error like this
[image]

why my imageview working but textview not working

thank you for attention

Comment: Don't paste the code in 3rd party websites and give us a link unless it required I recommend you to edit your question with complete code

Comment: ok please check again

Comment: are you sure that it's your item_post.xml code ?

Answer (score 3):

```
mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, checkList.get(getAdapterPosition()), getAdapterPosition(), list.get(getAdapterPosition()));
```

change to

```
mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, checkList.get(getAdapterPosition()), getAdapterPosition(), list.get(getAdapterPosition()));
```

Comment: You had using Imageview(imglike) view but you need to use your viewholder view that's why your app is crashed.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **id** *tvKonten* does not exist. In your XML code, the id of the TextView is ***txtsuka***, not *tvKonten*. Change *tvKonten* to *txtsuka*.

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot attach my posting

Comment: I have also thought the same but actually the xml code @senaa posted is not complete it's just a part ... he added complete code in pastebin there is a link check it

Comment: please check my xml code https://pastebin.com/R3LD6sTH

Answer (score 0):

Try these options, it might work for you :

1. Invalidate Caches and Restart
2. Check if you have a different version of the same layout file in your res folder such as `...v26.xml` or something like that ; if you find any then delete the unwanted version of the file.

Comment: I have tried number 1 then number two i don't have different version

Comment: try changing id of text view and see what happens...

Comment: The line on which you are getting an error, is it inside your Activity file inside the listener implementation? @senaa